# Why 99 reputation is required for "Create new tags", why not 100?

Tags: discussion

Why 99 reputation is required for "Create new tags" on Meta, why not 100 ?

```
15       Vote up
15  Flag offensive
1   Leave comments†
100     Vote down (costs 1 rep)
100     Edit community wiki posts
1   Reduced advertising
250     Vote to close or reopen your questions
99  Create new tags
500     Retag questions
1000    Show total up and down vote counts
2000    Edit other people's posts
3000    Vote to close or reopen any questions
10000   Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the idea was that if you linked your account to get +100 on Meta (giving a total of 101 rep), you could take a downvote on your first question, and still be able to create a tag when asking a second question.

Comment: You can't really predict that sequence of events, less to plan for it.

Comment: @Dev: Agreed, but I remember Jeff saying this somewhere... of course it was probably in a comment so I'll never be able to find it.

Comment: I thought meta didn't get the +100 rep for acct-linking?  At least I never got any...

Comment: To me, putting 99 on edit CW would make more sense than on create new tags.

Comment: @Charles: At the time of association, you needed at least 200 rep on another site to get the bonus. If you think you missed out, e-mail team@stackoverflow.com, or post a question here on Meta.

Comment: @Charles: Or de-associate and re-associate your accounts. I think that has been reported to work.

Comment: @mmyers: That worked, I can report.  Thanks!